# parse.com: fetching only 100 results

Tags: parse-platform

I'm struggling with knowing how to get all the data

my code is

```
   $headers = array(
      "X-Parse-Application-Id: $APP_ID" ,
      "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: $REST_ID" ,
      "X-Parse-Master-Key : $MASTER_ID ",
       "Content-Type: application/json",
    );
   $ch = curl_init($url); 
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
   $response = curl_exec($ch);  
    $parse_data=json_decode($response,true);
    print_r($parse_data);
```

but i want to get all the data at once or more then hundred data

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

The default limit for REST-API calls is 100 objects but you can set a limit for your request (anything between 1 and 1000).

From the docs:

> "You can use the limit and skip parameters for pagination, limit
>   defaults to 100, but anything from 1 to 1000 is a valid limit."

[1] https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-constraints

Comment: yes [Björn Kaiser](http://stackoverflow.com/users/515042/bj%C3%B6rn-kaiser) i did it for 1000 but what if i have to get all the data at once

Comment: Read the documentation, limit and skip is all you need.

Comment: This is the answer of my issue. Thanks.